# How to format json comments in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, comments, javadoc

I need add some json in comment to let the comment clearly. But I found IntelliJ will remove all indentation, so is there plugins or methods let IntelliJ format the json in comment correctly? I have tried to find such plugins but they do not take effect at comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your json inside the comment with `<pre>` tags

Eg:

```
/*
 * <pre>
 * {
 *     json: "value1"
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
```

Intellij should ignore formatting alignment for text within `<pre>` tag in javadoc. (With default code style settings for java).